# How to convert python timestamp to javascript YYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.302325

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, datepicker

How can I convert a python timestamp with javacript

from 2014-07-28T20:45:04.271935

to 1.6.2014 (20:45)

I tried to use the builtin parse function from javascript, but it seems to mix up things..

```
    out = new Date(context);
    out = out.getDay() + ". " + out.getMonth() + ". " + out.getFullYear() + " (" + out.getHours()+ ":" + out.getMinutes() + ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with date and time intensively in your application I'd recommend you to use [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) library for painless conversions:

```
moment('2014-07-28T20:45:04.271935').format('D.M.YYYY (H:m)');
// Will return "28.7.2014 (20:45)"

moment('2014-07-09T20:45:04.271935').format('DD.MM.YYYY (H:m)');
// Will return "09.07.2014 (20:45)"
```

And if you need to format the date and time only in one place then just build the string manually as you did in your code example.